# How can I block Ctrl+Alt+Del when it's sent by BeyondTrust Privileged Remote Access to Windows 10 IoT Enterprise?

Tags: windows, keyboard

BeyondTrust Privileged Remote Access has a button to send Ctrl+Alt+Del to the remote system.  I've been able to block Ctrl+Alt+Del for non-remote use by using the `HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout`'s `Scancode Map` property and/or [Keyboard Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/keyboardfilter).  Neither of those block it when sent by Privileged Remote Access.  Is there a way to block it when sent by Privileged Remote Access?

In the meantime, I've disabled all of the options on the Ctrl+Alt+Del screen by running the following PowerShell code:

```
# Disable Ctrl+Alt+Del screen Switch User option.
New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System -Name HideFastUserSwitching -Value 1

# Disable remaining Ctrl+Alt+Del screen options.
New-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer -Name NoLogoff -Value 1
New-Item -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies -Name System
New-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System -Name DisableChangePassword -Value 1
New-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System -Name DisableLockWorkstation -Value 1
New-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System -Name DisableTaskMgr -Value 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably two ways to trigger C+A+D in software:

- Keyboard driver. Not sure if the scancode map would handle that.
- Simulate. Microsoft used to provide a library on request with a function called `SimulateSAS`. Windows 7 added [`SendSAS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sas/nf-sas-sendsas) for everyone to use. There is also [3rd-party stuff that does it](https://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/tag/saslibex/).

The group policy "Disable or enable software Secure Attention Sequence" can disable the simulation. A driver can be disabled/removed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  Device Manager says that there is a HID Keyboard Device that's using the Microsoft driver.  Are you suggesting that another keyboard driver could be generating the sequence?  I enabled the "Disable or enable software Secure Attention Sequence" policy and set it to None, but Ctrl+Alt+Del via Privileged Remote Access still worked.  :(